# Format %c expects argument of type char* but has int

Tags: c, parsing, char, scanf

So I know I've defined the char. But something is annoying the compiler.

```
        char direction;
        int exit, firstLine, length;
        firstLine = 0, exit = 0;

        /* Boolean for the whether size has been read. */
        while (((fgets(line, sizeof(line), boardFile)) != NULL) || exit == 1)
        { 
            if (firstLine == 0)                                     /* Easy way of handling reading width/height. */
            {
                /* Split for size and width. */
                sscanf(line, "%d,%d", widthPtr, heightPtr);             /* Store width and height inside width/height. */
                firstLine++;
                if (VALIDSIZE(*widthPtr))
                {
                    if (!(VALIDSIZE(*heightPtr)))
                    {
                        printf("%d is an invalid Height. Must be between 1 and 12 (Inclusive).", *heightPtr);
                        exit = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%d is an invalid Width. Must be between 1 and 12 (Inclusive).", *widthPtr);
                    exit = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Ship* newShip;
                sscanf(line, "%s %c %d %[^\n]", location, direction, &length, name);    /* Parse into vars. */
                newShip = createStruct(location, direction, length, name);              /* Need a createStruct method so it doesn't store the same Struct in the same memory location. */
                insertLast(list, newShip);                                              /* Add to the list of structs. */
            }
```

The error I'm getting

`format %c expects argument of type char* but argument has type int.`

I'm trying to read in this string

`D4 E 3 NullByte Sub`

It was working as a char* but I needed it to be a char since it's only one character anyway.

The E is what I'm trying to scan into the char and the scanf is what is throwing the error.

Any help is great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a MCVE that I can compile and test, you probably needed to write

```
sscanf(line, "%s %c %d %[^\n]", location, &direction, &length, name);
```

That is, the argument corresponding to `%c` needed to be a pointer to `char`, just as the one for `%d` needed to be a pointer to `int`.

You got a confusing message that mentioned `int` because of a historical quirk of C: variadic function parameters (the `...` after a format string) are still promoted using the old rules from before ANSI C.  So, a `char` gets widened to `int`.  This was for backward-compatibility with code from the ’70s and ’80s.